# Is it acceptable to edit (correct) grammar or spelling?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spelling, grammar

Some individuals may be sensitive to edits of their posts on the basis of spelling or grammar. Some editors may be concerned about what to put in as a reason/explanation for the edit. New editors, in general, are likely uncertain of what the accepted "etiquette" is, on these sites, for such corrections.

Comment: Note that there is no reason to correct end phrases with thanks in them because they should be wholly removed anyway. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I just meant the general incorrect usage of allot/alot. I do know that thanks and greetings are removed.

Comment: I sometimes put a link to [this great thing](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) in the edit summary in this case. :)

Comment: That is a hilarious post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spelling and grammar corrections are acceptable - anything that improves a question is a good thing.

What you put in the summary is up to you - "Improved spelling/grammar" is an option.

Though the purpose of SO is not to teach English, helping people understand the edits and thus improve their English is a good thing - so your first option will have more benefit for the OP.

Comment: +1 for your words. I asked a question which was very similar to the original poster's, in this case it was an every/ever typo; one which I frequently make myself, and my reputation was downvoted here on meta.stackoverflow more than any other single post I've ever made.

Comment: @User.1 - On Meta, downvotes tend to mean disagreement. I doubt anyone downvoted your question over spelling/grammar.